# jQuery 'change' Event Not Firing On All Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function that does a few things with two number fields values passed to it.

- Prevent use of decimals/periods for either number
- Check that second number is less than first
- Show/Hide supporting validation messages

Everything seems to work as expected except that the event that checks if the second number is less than the first only works for the last instance of when the function is called. e.g. on the last group pair of fields checked. However, the rest of the function works on all fields.

I'm not understanding why the event comparing values only works the final time the function is called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cchoma_mc/L349u2jp/12/

```js
function validate_participating ($serves, $participating) {
        
        num_serves = $($serves);
        num_participating = $($participating);

        $.merge(num_serves, num_participating).keydown(function(e){
            var kCode = (e.which || e.keyCode)
            if(kCode == 190 || kCode == 110) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('.ginput_container').find('.instruction').addClass('validation_message gfield_validation_message').text('Decimal points are disallowed. Please enter whole numbers only.').show();
                $(this).focusout(function(){
                    $(this).closest('.ginput_container').find('.instruction').hide();
                });
            }

        });


        $.merge(num_serves, num_participating).change(function(){

            if ( parseInt(num_participating.val()) > parseInt(num_serves.val()) ) {

        $(this).closest('.ginput_container').find('.instruction').addClass('validation_message gfield_validation_message').text('Participating cannot be greater than serves.').show();
            } else if ( parseInt(num_participating.val()) <= parseInt(num_serves.val()) ) {
                $(num_serves).closest('.ginput_container').find('.instruction').hide();
                $(num_participating).closest('.ginput_container').find('.instruction').hide();
            }

        });
    
    }

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    validate_participating('#input_451_252', '#input_451_576');
    validate_participating('#input_451_254', '#input_451_577');
    validate_participating('#input_451_255', '#input_451_578');
 
});
```

```css
.gfield {
  margin-bottom:16px;
}
.instruction {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_id">


<div id="field_451_252" class="gfield gfield--width-half gf-mc-hide-instruction mc-gf-subfield mc-gf-remove-row-gap gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible" style=""><label class="gfield_label" for="input_451_252">Indicate the number of students this program serves at full capacity<span class="gfield_required"><span class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk">*</span></span></label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number"><input name="input_252" id="input_451_252" type="number" step="any" min="0" value="" class="large" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_451_252"><div class="instruction " id="gfield_instruction_451_252">Please enter a number greater than or equal to <strong>0</strong>.</div></div></div>

<div id="field_451_576" class="gfield gfield--width-half gf-mc-hide-instruction mc-gf-subfield mc-gf-remove-row-gap gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible" style=""><label class="gfield_label" for="input_451_576">Total unique headcount of students that participated in this activity<span class="gfield_required"><span class="gfield_required gfield_required_asterisk">*</span></span></label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number"><input name="input_576" id="input_451_576" type="number" step="any" min="0" value="" class="large" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_451_576"><div class="instruction " id="gfield_instruction_451_576">Please enter a number greater than or equal to <strong>0</strong>.</div></div></div>
<br><br>
<div id="field_451_254" class="gfield gfield--width-half gf-mc-hide-instruction mc-gf-subfield mc-gf-remove-row-gap field_sublabel_below field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible" style=""><label class="gfield_label" for="input_451_254">Students with one or more disabilities eligible</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number"><input name="input_254" id="input_451_254" type="number" step="any" min="0" value="" class="large" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_451_254"><div class="instruction " id="gfield_instruction_451_254">Please enter a number greater than or equal to <strong>0</strong>.</div></div></div>

<div id="field_451_577" class="gfield gfield--width-half gf-mc-hide-instruction mc-gf-subfield mc-gf-remove-row-gap field_sublabel_below field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible" style=""><label class="gfield_label" for="input_451_577">Students with one or more disabilities participating</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number"><input name="input_577" id="input_451_577" type="number" step="any" min="0" value="" class="large" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_451_577"><div class="instruction " id="gfield_instruction_451_577">Please enter a number greater than or equal to <strong>0</strong>.</div></div></div>
<br><br>
<div id="field_451_255" class="gfield gfield--width-half gf-mc-hide-instruction mc-gf-subfield mc-gf-remove-row-gap field_sublabel_below field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible" style=""><label class="gfield_label" for="input_451_255">Low-income students eligible</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number"><input name="input_255" id="input_451_255" type="number" step="any" min="0" value="" class="large" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_451_255"><div class="instruction " id="gfield_instruction_451_255">Please enter a number greater than or equal to <strong>0</strong>.</div></div></div>

<div id="field_451_578" class="gfield gfield--width-half gf-mc-hide-instruction mc-gf-subfield mc-gf-remove-row-gap field_sublabel_below field_description_above gfield_visibility_visible" style=""><label class="gfield_label" for="input_451_578">Low-income students participating</label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_number"><input name="input_578" id="input_451_578" type="number" step="any" min="0" value="" class="large" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="gfield_instruction_451_578"><div class="instruction " id="gfield_instruction_451_578">Please enter a number greater than or equal to <strong>0</strong>.</div></div></div>


    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If I did understand you correctly, the example works for me. Note that the `change` event is deferred until the element loses focus. Also, consider adding `console.log()` outputs at the beginning of your `change` function for debugging/understanding the functionality.

Comment: @michip96 - It's not working for the first two input groups. Enter a number in the first, then a larger number in the second and it fails except for the last pair of inputs.

Comment: Your (first) issue is that `num_serves`/`num_participating` are *implied global` variables.  So the 2nd/3rd time you run, those variables are overwritten with the last iteration - when the event then fires it uses the last value for `parseInt(num_participating.val()` so it only compares the last 2 values, but because you use `$(this).closest` to show the message the message is shown on the first 2 (on change of them), but only if the last one fails.   Put `let ` in front of each: https://jsfiddle.net/y47baLqs/

Comment: Your second issue may be that press "." always hides the instruction (on focusout) so may hide the instruction after change has shown it.  Maybe focusout runs first?

Comment: @freedomn-m - Looks like you found it. Seems to be working for me. Consider posting as answer for credit. Thanks so much!